# Keepalived with EC2 Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, high-availability, keepalived, amazon-elastic-ip

I've tried once to use Keepalived with EC2 Elastic IP failover but default Keepalived configuration was unstable as IP address begin to flapping due to switchover delays and doesn't come back to MASTER in case of any network or API related issues.
I've increased fall and rise values for Keepalived check scripts and added more checks to verify Elastic IP owner and Amazon API availability, so now I have solution that works fine in my test scenarios (code is available at GitHub https://github.com/fedordikarev/aws_ha_keepalived).
Are there any other issues with Keepalived and Elastic IP I should concern about and add more checks or tweaks for Keepalived to get fully stable solution?